# Sub categories shopware5

Tags: shopware

I am using a custom theme in Shopware, the parent theme is "Bare" theme, when I need to use some data or alter existing data, still I do not understand how I can do this using controllr, plugin or widgets.

Example:- I need to display "sub categories" on my home page main menu.
When I use "{debug}" on my index.tpl I can see all the main categories but the sub categories are not available even though I have created and activated sub categories on my back end.

I checked the configurations settings to make sure if anything is blocking it from showing on front end. 
What kind of approach I should use to get this thing done. 
What is the solution? 
Update index controller? 
Any CMS option to enable /disable?
install a plugin?
create a widget?

FYI: This is what I can see on my debug screen on home page (index.tpl)

```
$sCategory
 flag => false
 subcategories => Array (0)
 childrenCount => 2
 7 => Array (23)
 id => 7
 name => "IVORY & WHITE"
 metaKeywords => null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plugin called AdvancedMenu which has to be activated via the Plugin Manager. In the plugin's config you are able to define the nesting level of how deep the category should be shown. This setting set to 2 by default, I guess. After activating the plugin there should be a new variable $sAdvancedMenu available in the Smarty template.

Please have a look: http://en.community.shopware.com/_detail_1602.html?_ga=1.192119343.464766896.1445350898

**Another way (without the AdvancedMenu plugin) would be as follows:**

There is a Shopware Core class available via `Shopware()->Modules()->Categories()` that contains a method called `sGetWholeCategoryTree($current)`. This method returns the whole category subtree for any given root category. But in that case you need to create a plugin that is listening to the `Enlight_Controller_Front_PostDispatch` event or any similar. After assigning the tree to the view you will have access to a hierarchical multidimensional array of categories with their related children.

Comment: This is a good solution when you ahve the plugin. I need to have this information about subcategories and subsubcategories (etc.) without the plugin. I am guessing that is what @chathuraka asked too.

Comment: In that case there is a Shopware Core class available via `Shopware()->Modules()->Categories()` that contains a method called `sGetWholeCategoryTree($current)`. This method returns the whole category subtree for any given root category. But in that case you need to create a plugin that is listening to the "Enlight_Controller_Front_PostDispatch" event or any similar. After assigning the tree to the view you will have access to

Comment: this is exactly what I did after some tedious research, and it worked! Please make an answer here, so that I can accept it as the correct answer, since it is the best solution I could think of.

Comment: I did edit the original answer by adding the described alternative way.